# Using aliases in other aliases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alias

Is there a better way to use aliases in aliases?

For instance I don't believe I can do something like `select ... sum(...) as sum1, sum(...) as sum2, (sum1 + sum2) as sum3`

So far I've needed to save off all these subqueries for any new column that references an alias. For instance, `sum(...) as sum1, sum(...) as sum2` in one query, saved off as something like `q1`, and then in some new query, having `(q1.sum1 + q1.sum2) as sum3`

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Subqueries or CTEs is how you do this.

Comment: So the way I am doing it is already correct?

Comment: You haven't shown code in your question.

Comment: I gave an example line - but what I mean by subqueries, might be something like `sum(...) as sum1, sum(...) as sum2` in one query, save it off as something like `q1`, and then in some new query, having `(q1.sum1 + q1.sum2) as sum3`

Comment: In SQL Server, and most databases (some exceptions) you can't reference a column alias in the same select due to the order of operations; use either a `derived table` or `cte` - or repeat the expression - SQL Server will only calculate it once.

Comment: Look at CROSS APPLY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't aggregate an alias in an alias.  However, you can do something like the following:

```
Select ...
      ,sum1 = sum( col1 ) 
      ,sum2 = sum( col2 ) 
      ,sum3 = sum( col1 + col2 )
 From  YourTable
 Group By ...
```

**EDIT - Update**

```
Select *
      ,sum3 = sum1+sum2
 From  (
         Select ...
               ,sum1 = sum( {some complex case} ) 
               ,sum2 = sum( {some complex case} ) 
          From  YourTable
         Group By ...
       ) A
```

Comment: But if I have some complicated expression (e.g. a CASE-WHEN statement or something) instead of `col1` by itself for example, I will need to repeat that complicated thing in both spots, correct?

Comment: @user525966 Yes that is correct.   Then I would go with Gordon's suggestion using a sub-query or cte.

Comment: Is that different from what I am already doing?

Comment: @user525966 See EDIT - Update

Comment: If trying to re-use a CASE-WHEN, I recommend using my CROSS APPLY method (see my answer) for a more succinct query than CTE/temp tables

Answer (score 0):

**Reusing Code using CROSS APPLY**

Most people use CTE's/temp tables, but here's a little trick particularly succinct if you need to stack calculations like when parsing strings. Cannot use this trick for aggregate functions (SUM,COUNT,etc...), but can use this for string parsing, numbers crunching, conditionals, etc...

```
Select A.*,B.Calc1,C.Calc2
FROM TableA AS A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Calc1 = CASE WHEN...END) AS B /*Calculated column*/
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Calc2 = A.Col1 + B.Calc2 ) AS C /*Can reference columns in previous CROSS APPLY's*/
```